# How does 'use' know where to start searching for the file?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I've created a controller in Laravel which uses the following `use`:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

How does the controller know where to find `Request`?
The controller itself is in:

```
app\Http\Controllers\LoginController.php
```

But Request is in:

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request.php
```

---

---

So why is the `use`:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

...and not:

```
use vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Would this also work?
How does the controller know where to start searching?

Comment: `use` doesn't know where to find a file, because it references a class, not a file; hopefully the autoloader knows where to find the file for that class

Comment: It seems like there are multiple autoloaders, how does it know which is the right one?

Comment: If you are using composer for autoloading, check directory `vendor/composer` to read the autoloaders.

Comment: How does it know which autoloader? It doesn't... the autoload process simply asks each registered autoloader in turn until either one of them loads the file, or doesn't respond correctly (e.g. a badly written autoloader) or it's asked them all and none of them have found the file (in which case you get a class not found exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on information your application has already supplied to PHP by the `namespace` declaration in your class files — and, usually, via an autoloader. By default, your classes would not be found.

It could be that:

- you've manually included the files
- you are using an autoloader

Unless it's a small project the first option will get unmanageable quickly so you'd be better off exploring the second option. As @Koala Yeung has mentioned PSR-0 and PSR-4 are the generally accepted way to do this.

You register an autoloader with `spl_autoload_register` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) and this allows you to write a function that is called every time you create a new object.

If you run `var_dump(spl_autoload_functions());` you will see the autoloaders Laravel has set up.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel uses [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) in its core and have a [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) / [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) compatible autoloader.

The PSR-0 and PSR-4 standard dictates how to resolve folder according to the namespace. And laravel's [Autoloader](http://alanstorm.com/laravel_5_autoloader/), through PHP's [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) helps to do resolve and include the correct file.

Comment: Would it also work if I specify the whole path like I did? e.g. `use vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: No. It wouldn't. The `use` keyword is taking the [namespace path](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for the class. Not actual file path. They looks similar because the PSR-0 / PSR-4 say so. They effectively say, "Hey, how about we find file according to namespace path". You should read [PSR-4 spec](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for more details.

Comment: But the namespace is `namespace App\Http\Controllers` so why are they using `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` instead of `use ..\..\..\Illuminate\Http\Request;` if they start from the namespace?

Comment: The [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) described in details how they propose to resolve file path. Different vendor namespace (e.g. `Illuminate`) get resolved to a different folder. The namespace mapping can be found in [Autoloading config](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) of the [composer.json](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) in your project root.

Comment: Also I don't think `..\..\..\Illuminate\Http\Request` is a correct namespace format. If you read the [PHP documentation site](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php), it states that if a namespace is not found locally, it will [fallback to global namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php). Thus in your case, if `\App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Http\Request` is not found, it will fallback and search `\Illuminate\Http\Request`.